# jQuery datatable in different formats like excel, pdf

Tags: jquery, datatable, colors, background-color

```
$('.dataTables-example').DataTable({
            pageLength: 25,
            dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
            buttons: [
                { extend: 'copy' },
                { extend: 'csv' },
                { extend: 'excel', title: 'ExampleFile' },
                { extend: 'pdfHtml5', title: 'Product Information', messageTop: 'Hi this is pdf message title options', messageBottom: 'Footer PDF show' },
                {
                    extend: 'print',
                    customize: function (win) {
                        $(win.document.body).addClass('white-bg');
                        $(win.document.body).css('font-size', '10px');

                        $(win.document.body).find('table')
                                .addClass('compact')
                                .css('font-size', 'inherit');
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
```

I am exporting data from jQuery datatable in different formats like excel, pdf. Some cells have a different background color in data table. But those colors are not displaying in exported excel or pdf. Can anyone tell me, how to solve this problem?

Comment: Solution helpful to you?

Comment: Thank you Bhumi Shah. It is working now. However i need to add different colors to each column with dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add color like this https://jsfiddle.net/fj80vtur/1/

```
$('#example').DataTable({
            pageLength: 25,
            dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
            buttons: [
                { extend: 'copy' },
                { extend: 'csv' },
                { extend: 'excel', title: 'ExampleFile',
                        customize: function (xlsx) {
                            var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
                            $('row:first c', sheet).attr('s', '7');
                            $('row c[r^="C"]',sheet).each(function(){
                                    $(this).attr('s', '36');
                                      });
                     }
                },
            ]
        });
```

Comment: My requirements is like Column C, D,E and F has multiple color combination such as Red, Yellow and Green and based on some rule need to display color in each cell. Can you please tell me how to do it dynamically ?